# Configuring result file data when running JMeter in non-GUI mode

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm currently running JMeter in Non-GUI mode via:

```
"apache-jmeter/bin/jmeter -n -t $testPlan.jmx -l results.jtl"
```

When the tests finish running, the results.jtl file contains something like this:

```
1379545163610,186,HTTP Request,403,Forbidden,Service 1-30,text,false,239,186
```

It appears that it's using a default configuration for what should be outputted, but what if I'm interested in seeing only the latencies per line instead this big csv value? I know that when you use JMeter in GUI mode, and when you add a new listener such as "View Results In Table", you can configure what exactly should be written to the resulting jtl file such as response code, latency, thread name, etc.

I just want the latency data, however. How can configure this through this command line instead of through the GUI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update: The following is correct, but it's considered best practice to modify the `user.properties` file in order to avoid updates which may overwrite `jmeter.properties` (See the [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#introduction)).**

Check out following set of properties in jmeter.properties.

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Results file configuration
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# This section helps determine how result data will be saved.
# The commented out values are the defaults.

# legitimate values: xml, csv, db.  Only xml and csv are currently supported.
#jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv

...
...
# Only applies to CSV format files:
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
```

print_field_names is by default false. Set it to true to figure out what column is what?

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,bytes,Latency
1379564790444,652,jp@gc - Dummy Sampler,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,87,78
1379564791099,1,Debug Sampler,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,1175,0
```

By the way that big value is timestamp in epoch, if you meant 1st field by `big value`.

Answer (score 1):

By default JMeter does not save any summary results to file. Either you have to save as JTL and view it in the summary listeners later or run with the summary listeners. I would rather suggest the first option, as the second will be a overhead for the JMeter.
Also i have read an post on how few summary can be logged on console while running in non-GUI mode. Please read - http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/using-apache-jmeter-in-non-gui-mode/