# Jmeter - running command line arg -l doesn't log headers

Tags: jmeter

Does anyone know if it is possible when using the -l switch on command line to execute, if you can log the headers in the .jtl file as well?  I've actually named mine as .csv (read somewhere it doesn't matter) but no headers are appearing.

If this is not possible, can someone please tell me the what the headings should be?

Cheers,
J

Comment: Sorry, what are you actually looking for? Request/response headers? Or column names in CSV file? This is managed by jmeter.save.saveservice.* in jmeter.properties. Although I don't get what it has in common with `-l` option.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for **HTTP request and response headers**:

1. Storing headers in "csv" mode is not supported, you will have to switch to "xml" mode
2. It is unclear whether you look for "request" or "response" headers.

Kindly find the instructions on how to switch JMeter to store results in XML format and "tell" JMeter to store request and response headers:

1. Command-line mode:

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true -n -t /path/to/your/script.jmx -l /path/to/results/file.jtl
   ```
2. Unattended mode:

   - Locate *user.properties* file in /bin folder of your JMeter installation
   - Add the next 3 lines to the *user.properties* file:

     ```
     jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
     jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
     jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
     ```

   and after JMeter restart the properties will get applied.

---

If you're looking for printing **field names in CSV mode like** like `timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,success,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,Connect` etc.

1. Command-line mode:

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true -n -t ....
   ```
2. Unattended mode: add the next line to *user.properties* file

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
   ```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for comprehensive information on different JMeter properties and ways of setting and/or overriding them

Comment: You DON'T need to use XML format to see headers in CSV file.

Comment: My dear little indian friend, why do you think your answer based on a broken link is better than mine?

Comment: First, it is most simple by far from your response. I've removed my denotation.
And it's funny you edited your post to fit to my answer as if you wrote it IN THE FIRST PLACE

Comment: Second, it is obvious that a russion guy will be assulted first, and not be able to accept that someone has a better and simpler solution, even if he's not indian.

Comment: jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true will not work in CLI mode UNLESS you put it in the user.properties!

Comment: . 1. your statement doesn't contain the answer 2. Your answer contains information which is not true. ![I will test my solution prior to posting it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob7pE.png)

Answer (score 0):

See this post on how to add headers to csv output file.
You need to configure it in the jmeter.properties (Command switch won't work with this since it has to be defined first):
 [Configuring result file data when running JMeter in non-GUI mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883741/configuring-result-file-data-when-running-jmeter-in-non-gui-mode)

The print_field_names is by default false.
Edit jmeter.properties file in the Jmeter home directory, and set:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Results file configuration
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# This section helps determine how result data will be saved.
# The commented out values are the defaults.

# legitimate values: xml, csv, db.  Only xml and csv are currently supported.
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv

...
...
# Only applies to CSV format files:
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
```

And run from command line:

```
\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t C:\Jmeter\Tests\Test.jmx -l Results.csv
```

Output example:

```
timeStamp;elapsed;label;responseCode;threadName;success;bytes;grpThreads;allThreads;Latency;SampleCount;ErrorCount;Hostname
11:49:16;32;Get the Agent ID;500;SM play 10 calls per user 1-1;false;0;1;1;0;1;1;HOST1
```

Comment: Dmitri T, did you check my answer?
I've corrected the link - don't know what happened...